# PHP version 5.6.17 unexpected T function/anonymous function error

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, anonymous-function

I have a local Drupal site running with MAMP on Win 7 with php 5.6.13. My live site has php 5.6.17. I have no problems on the local site, but on the live site I get unexpected T function error with the following code which I downloaded from drupal.org.

```
function redhen_activity_message_types() {
  $message_types = array_keys(message_type_load());
  $filtered = array_filter($message_types, function($var) {
    return strpos($var, 'redhen_') !== FALSE;
  });
  return $filtered;
}
```

The line beginning with $filtered is the one that is pointed to by the error message.

I know little about php, but have been searching the web and found something called anonymous functions not working on older versions of php. Is the slightly different versions of php causing this problem? How do I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Anonymous functions (also known as lambda functions or closures) were added in PHP 5.3, so the version should not be an issue. A possibility is the version of PHP that your live site is using is not what you are reporting (many hosts allow multiple PHP versions for instance). Can you try run `phpinfo();`? One way is to make a file called `phpinfo.php` with the contents: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`, upload it to your website's web root and access it in a browser.

Comment: Can you double double check that the version of PHP that is being used to run this code is actually the same version you have quoted. What tanerkuc said - run a phpinfo() inside the exact same file if you can and run it in the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) is the function that's defined starting in that line of code:

```
function($var) {
  return strpos($var, 'redhen_') !== FALSE;
}
```

I don't see anything obviously wrong with that function, and Redhen CRM gets enough use that others are likely to have run into problems already if it were clearly incorrect. And while it's always good to test under the same version as your production environment it's unlikely that there was bug introduced to PHP between 5.6.13 and 5.6.17 that's causing this problem.

To find the root cause try a few things:

1. Check to make sure the version of PHP you think is running in production is actually running.  I've seen several environments recently where people had a different version running under php-cli than on the web server, meaning that running `php --version` on the command line gave the wrong answer.  Use a `phpinfo()` call to verify the version.
2. Check the [Redhen issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/redhen) for other people with the same problem.
3. Update your test machine to match production. Once you're sure production is the version you think it is, set your dev environment to match and see if the problem comes back.  If it does, try to move forward to a more current minor version and see if the error goes away again.

Comment: I have confirmed that my live site is at php 5.6.17. Drupal admin/reports/status then click more information to run phpinfo(). (Apparently Drupal runs this in the background & displays this in the Status Report.) Both Status Report & phpinfo() report 5.6.17. My live site is at bluehost.com. It offers only the 5.6.17 release of PHP. MAMP offers only PHP 5.6.0, 5.6.8, and 5.6.13 thus making it difficult to get both local & remote in sync unless I can figure out a way to add 5.6.17 to MAMP. Got any ideas?

Comment: I found no reports of problems like mine at the Redhen issue queue.

Comment: Closures have been supported since 5.3 @SamStamport. If you're positive that the context you're receiving the error in is definitely using php 5.6, then you need to contact your hosting company and ask them to fix their dodgy software. It really is that simple, closures work in php 5.6, and you wouldn't see that error with a proper installation of it. For the record, it's far, far more likely that you're actually executing your code in php5.2 for whatever reason. Maybe you have a different of PHP for CLI and this is happening during a cron run invoked from the server, for example.

Comment: What are "closures"?

Comment: Anonymous functions are closures.